# Delete Data after x failed passwords

Tags: encryption

Iphone has a delete data setting where if the password is failed 10 times then the data gets deleted on the iphone. How is this done? Wouldn't a hacker who has access to the phone be able to duplicate it's contents and get infinite many tries?

How can you truly protect your data when someone else has access to it?

Comment: Question seems more appropriate for https://security.stackexchange.com/. Anyways, the short answer is: When someone has access to the hardware, there is no guaranteed way to delete the data after *n* failed login attempts.

Comment: As far I know - the idea is that the content is encrypted, the encryption key is protected by a hardware chip. Providing invalid passwords will make the chip "forget" the encryption key. Nothing is perfect, but at least it is not so easy to read or duplicate chip's state.